# REGEXP_REPLACE not working as expected for replacing chars wrapt in commas

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to use REGEXP_REPLACE to clean string values that have `''` wrapping them, and I tried this:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE("Stacko 'N' verflow",'([A-Z])','\\1')
```

I expect to get `Stacko N verflow`, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This should work. `REGEXP_REPLACE("Stacko 'N' verflow","'([A-Z])'", "$1")`. Example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cLMENtdAYHJRKcSmuQKeeZ/1

Comment: (Terminology:  Those "commas" are called "apostrophes" or "single quotes".  This is a comma:  `,` .)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match single quotes, you have to include them in your pattern. Also use `$1` for the captured value. Try:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE('Stacko ''N'' verflow', '''([A-Z])''', '$1')
```

And don't enclose string literals in double quotes. SQL uses single quotes for that.